# Best learning resource for HTML5/CSS3 for a programmer?

Tags: html, css

I was just wondering what you thought would be the best education material for HTML5/CSS3 is (not older web technologies) for a guy who is just a programmer (i.e. mostly C/C++, Java, Pascal, and Python)? Reason I ask, is because the HTML and CSS syntax mostly confuses me, and there are some things I just do not understand (e.g. the `float` styling attribute, I usually just end up putting that somewhere and hoping it works, if not, try putting it somewhere else). So I was hoping there was an *explicit* guide/tutorial on getting a programmer up to speed on HTML5/CSS3.

Alternatively, if there is no direct answer to that question, then what is a good learning resource for HTML5/CSS3 and what are the pitfalls/shortcomings (if any) in the markup language that I/others might encounter on this journey/transition?

Keep in mind I have minimal experience writing HTML/CSS markup, and have written no HTML5/CSS3 markup *at all*.

Regards and thank you in advance. :-)

EDIT: I hoped someone would answer my initial question: is there any nice documentation for programmers to easily pick up the language? (not really after a guide designed for absolute language beginners, just a nice *transitional* document).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally have used treehouse which is very helpful...

Link: [Tree House](http://teamtreehouse.com/)

Referral Link: [Tree House - Referral Link](http://referrals.trhou.se/aaronhatton)

If you are a student you can email for student discount as well!

**EDIT**

So here is the best documentation places to use for referring back to:

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) - Good for if you have something you are stuck with to ask

[W3Schools - HTML](http://w3schools.com/html/default.asp) - Good for simple guides and tutorials

[W3Schools - CSS](http://w3schools.com/css/default.asp) - Good for simple guides and tutorials

[PHP.net - PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/) - Definitely the place I would say most PHP coders use to refer back to for help

[W3C - HTML & CSS](http://www.w3.org/standards/webdesign/htmlcss) - This website is basically the industry standard regulator, you will find alot of websites have the W3C HTML Valid image

Comment: It isn't really, sorry. :( Please see my edit I made a couple of days ago to clarify my question.

Comment: @Mayazcherquoi there you go :)

Answer (score 0):

I am still a learner myself, but HTML/CSS is not as hard as programming. 
But as with Programming, there is always Good coding and bad coding practices.

I would start with knowing HTML basics first, then move on to CSS to compliment it. 
CSS is powerful. With time and practice, you will surely succeed.

Some object to the usage of this site, but when I started, I found this site mostly a good intro to HTML/CSS. On the top left is a menu for: HTML/CSS.
I am sure there are plenty of other sites out there, but this site started me off.

http://www.w3schools.com/

good luck.

You cold also go here: its short and sweet. 
http://www.htmldog.com/guides/html/

Answer (score 0):

This is good --> http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/30-html-best-practices-for-beginners/

Or this --> https://teamtreehouse.com/ (Payment)